# Where's the bug in this BitTorrent client's piece verification process?

Tags: c, bittorrent

I've been working on writing a BitTorrent client in C in my spare time. However -- seemingly at random -- my client will fail to verify that a received piece of a torrent is correct with the message:

```
Failed to verify piece: #4
```

Background: a .torrent file contains the relevant metadata for the file-to-be-downloaded, including a SHA1 hash of each piece (a block of the file-to-be-downloaded), so -- after downloading a piece -- I take its SHA1 hash and compare it to the one provided by the torrent's metadata file.

Here's the code that handles verification:

```
 int verify_piece (void* addr, uint64_t piece_length, unsigned char* piece_sha)
 {
     SHA_CTX sha;
     unsigned char sha1result[20];

     SHA1_Init(&sha);
     SHA1_Update(&sha, addr, piece_length);
     SHA1_Final(sha1result, &sha);

     if (memcmp(sha1result, piece_sha, 20)) {
          printf("Expected: ");
          print_sha1(piece_sha);
          printf("Received: ");
          print_sha1(sha1result);
          return 0;
     } else
          return 1;
  }
```

In an attempt to track down the bug, I rigged up two functions: `write_incorrect_piece()` and `write_correct_piece()`. The first function, `write_incorrect_piece()` is called when `verify_piece()` fails. It writes the piece that failed verification to a file so that I can inspect it with hexdump.

```
 void write_incorrect_piece (void* piece, uint32_t piece_length, uint32_t index)
 {
     FILE* failed_piece = fopen("failed_piece.out", "w+");

     write(fileno(failed_piece), piece, piece_length);
     fclose(failed_piece);
     printf("ERROR: Wrote piece #%d to failed_piece.out for inspection with hexdump.\n",
            index);

     write_correct_piece(piece_length, index);
     exit(1);
 }
```

As you can see, `write_incorrect_piece()` takes the parameters `void* piece`, which is a pointer to the piece which failed verification, `uint32_t piece_length`, which is the length of the piece, and `uint32_t index` which is the index of the piece which failed verification. It then copies the incorrect piece to a file called failed_piece.out.

You'll notice that before calling `exit()`, `write_incorrect_piece()` calls the function `write_correct_piece()`. This is the second function I wrote to help with debugging this error. It takes a known good version of the file that the torrent client is attempting to download (known_good.iso) and then copies the relevant piece to a file (correct_piece.out) so that I can compare it to the file containing the incorrect piece.

```
void write_correct_piece (uint32_t piece_length, uint32_t index)
{
     FILE* known_good = fopen("known_good.iso", "r+");
     FILE* correct_piece = fopen("correct_piece.out", "w+");

     /* get file size for MMAPing */
     struct stat st;
     stat("known_good.iso", &st);
     long size = st.st_size;

     void* addr = mmap(0,
                       size,
                       PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_SHARED,
                       fileno(known_good),
                       0);

     write(fileno(correct_piece), addr + piece_length * index, piece_length);
     munmap(addr, size);
     fclose(known_good);
     fclose(correct_piece);
}
```

I then took the two written files and formatted them with hexdump so that the output would be human readable and then tried to compare them via diff, like so

```
$ hexdump failed_piece.out > failed_piece.dump
$ hexdump correct_piece.out > correct_piece.dump
$ diff correct_piece.dump failed_piece.dump
```

To my surprise, diff didn't output anything. The files are exactly the same. Why, then, was the SHA1 hash of the piece different from the one expected by the torrent file? Perhaps, I then thought, the SHA1 hash from the metadata file was incorrect. If that's the case, I would expect the client to always fail to verify piece #4, so I modified the torrent client's scheduler to only attempt to download piece #4 to see if it does, in fact, always fail verification.

```
Successfully downloaded piece: #4
```

Wtf? Now I'm at an impasse. I figure a couple of different things could be causing this:

- There actually is a bug in the client's network code, but I have introduced a bug in `write_incorrect_piece()` and `write_correct_piece()` so that it produces two identical files regardless of the integrity of the inputs.
- There is a bug in `verify_piece()`, causing it to fail sporadically.
- I have failed to consider something.

For the life of me, however, I can't find any problems with any of the above code, so I'm hoping you fine folks can point out what I'm missing.

The entire source of the client is at https://github.com/robertseaton/slug.

**Edit:** Replaced `strncmp()` with `memcmp()` in `verify_piece()` and cleaned up both `write_incorrect_piece()` and `write_correct_piece()`.

**Edit:** Here's an example of the SHA1 hashes on a failed piece that seems correct when I manually diff it. As you can see, the hashes are not similar at all:

```
Expected: 239 66 216 164 16 120 73 24 1 236 116 173 144 85 243 152 160 165 64 231 
Received: 214 94 49 185 54 159 255 201 214 137 102 23 223 76 102 138 89 94 154 69 
Failed to verify piece: #13
```

Comment: One thing I see: You're comparing the hashes as strings - they're raw byte arrays, not strings, so it may contain embedded nulls.

Comment: Try adding some debug code just before verify_piece() returns 1 that dumps the two byte arrays to screen to see if they differ just in a byte och if they are completely different.

Comment: I don't like the way you casually mix usage of `fseek`, `write`, `fileno` and `mmap` (without closing the file and `munmap`ing), it's probably OK / works, but I find it suspect.  Why aren't you just doing `fwrite(piece, piece_length, 1, failed_piece); fclose(failed_piece);`?

Comment: I'd bet @NathanErnst is right.

Comment: @NathanErnst and @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi, I updated `verify_piece()` to use `memcmp()` instead of `strcmp()`, but the issue persists.

Comment: @Puppe, okay, I did as you suggested and I've added the results to my question.

Comment: @user786653, good point, I've cleaned up the functions (see edit), but the issue persists.

Comment: @NathanErnst actually, using strncmp() wouldn't cause the problem, if the hashes were equal, they would have the null character embedded in the same place and be of the same content and length. But he would only be comparing part of the hash, so it's still incorrect to use strncmp(), memcmp() is the correct thing for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so if we have a look at the invocation of `verify_piece()`, we see this:

```
 if (verify_piece(p->torrent->mmap + index * p->torrent->piece_length,
     p->torrent->piece_length, p->torrent->pieces[index].sha1)) {
```

Now, trivially, we know that the first and second parameters are correct since it is later reused when the program calls `write_incorrect_piece()` and we have already verified that its output is correct. So, we are free to focus on the third parameter, `p->torrent->pieces[index].sha1`.

At first glance, the parameter looks correct, since we are using `index` throughout the function. However, consider, what if `index` -- while perfectly valid on a correctly sorted array -- is being used as an index to an array that no longer contains the pieces in the assumed order?

*Viola!* Here's the culprit (in `__schedule()`):

```
qsort(t->pieces, t->num_pieces, sizeof(struct Piece), rarest);
```

Comment out the call to `qsort()` and the client runs as expected.